# recursive algorithm for fibonacci numbers?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Trying to figure out if I would use a recursive algorithm for fibonacci numbers. My problem is "Devise a recursive algorithm to find the n-th term of the function defined by $f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(n+1)= f(n)+2f(n-1)+1$ for $n=1,2\ldots$

Comment: You wrote $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+2a_{n-1}+1$ Isn't that recursive in and off itself?

Comment: I suppose that you want a closed form expression for $f(n)$. Is this correct ?

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13... Your sequence: 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 21, 42, 85, 170...  Your question: ??????

Comment: @DanielV. I suppose it is considered as a Fibonacci like sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the first terms of the sequence, you should notice that $$f(2n)=2 f(2n-1)$$ $$f(2n+1)=2f(2n)+1$$ which means $$f(2n+2)=4f(2n)+1$$ $$f(2n+1)=4f(2n-1)+1$$ By the way, this corresponds to the $A000975$ sequence in $OEIS$.

Using the above relations, you should be able to identify that $$f(n)=\frac{1}{6} \left(2^{n+2}-(-1)^n-3\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following algorithm:

```
input: n>=0
output: current
if n = 0 return current = 1
else
  let i = 1, current = 1, prev = 0, temp
  while i < n
    temp = current, current = temp + 2*prev + 1, prev = temp, i = i + 1
  return current
```

at the end of each step of the loop, current contains the $i^{th}$ term, prev the $(i-1)^{th}$; when you get out of it, $i=n$, and so current is then your solution.

Comment: This is fine but you compute all terms of the sequence up to $n$. I suppose that the OP wants a closed form for $f(n)$.

Comment: OP talks about a recursive algorithm.

Comment: For me the recursive algorithm was already in the question(as already said by   Sabyasachi) . I probably misunderstood. Cheers.